# for..in loop on object with index signature getting error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type..."

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to wrap my head around why TS is giving me an error despite med having defined the index. I do see that `slot` in `unEquip()` is treated as a string, but I don't know how I can type it, or why TS can't infer the type.

The error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type

Here's the code:

```
type Slot = 'head' | 'body' | 'hands' | 'feet' | 'accessory' | 'mainHand' | 'offHand'

const itemSlots: {
  [key in Slot]: string | null
} = {
  head: null,
  body: null,
  hands: null,
  feet: null,
  accessory: null,
  mainHand: null,
  offHand: null
}

const unEquip = (uuid: string) => {
  for (let slot in itemSlots) {
    if (itemSlots[slot] === uuid) {
      itemSlots[slot] = null
    }
  }
}
```

Also available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygNge2FAvFA5ACwgQwCbpQA%20GARgniISVjgHZ4DO1GAZhBMC%20jgMa8RGjBACcqxDAFscASzoAJegQnoErVooboAUNt4I6jZDOARJ8JIwBcUAN7aoUANoBrCCChzYiYAF0bRiJyAOYSdACucHDaAL6odg5Q2Pg2EVEANInklKmRcJmOmErWUGn5ieycuRmJfAJCoiDV5Y7Scpp4zQVQahpKzbG6%20obI4XQAogCO4TJg8QAU4TOdUIEhAJSoAHwJjqyiUPNwnKs%20nnSepuY%20jJv2jo4yrIcmZhbAjE6MPr6oKGhLGR4O6JB6XN43L4-eJlUFQGKJBExIA) in the TS playground.

I've looked at a lot of existing SO questions that are related, but they recommend using `any`, which I don't think is a good answer, *or* to define an index signature, which I've already done (to no avail). I've followed [this example](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#using-a-limited-set-of-string-literals) but the type is somehow still not inferred.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, using `slot as Slot`:

```
const unEquip = (uuid: string) => {
  for (let slot in itemSlots) {
    if (itemSlots[slot as Slot] === uuid) {
      itemSlots[slot as Slot] = null
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, this tells TS that `slot` is of type `Slot` rather than use the inferred type. I still don't understand how TS can not automatically infer the type though.